# Rotator or slideshow using jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I want to create a page that will have 9 images showing on the page and I will have a left and right arrow next to it. I then want to be able to click on one of those arrows and get taken to another set of 9 images.

I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. If anyone knows a good tutorial that I can do what I want please let me know.

Comment: I once used this plugin, you can have a look here - http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: I need something like this [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/06/09/grid-navigation-effects/) but instead of it going up and down I need it to go left and right.

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for SO, but if you want to have left-right scrolling, you can have a look at the link I mentioned earlier, it supports both horizontal and vertical scrolling. Or you can modify the behavior of the one you mentioned.